# Only use numbers in count sum Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below code that goes through my table and sums up all of the table values, and it works perfectly if the only thing in the table cell is a number.

I want to use it on a different table, that has letters and numbers in it, but I only want it to count the numbers, and not include the letters. (in the current code, if there is a letter at all in the table cell, it will count it as zero).

So... how would I modify this code to omit letters, and only count the numbers? Thanks!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
            if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>Confirmed: ' + sum + '</td></tr>';
    </script>
```

Comment: If a cell contains `Test123` you want to include `123` in the sum, or ignore the cell entirely if there are letters?

Comment: @DaveZych Just include "123" and not use "Test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic approach is to strip out non–digits and add what remains:

```
var re = /\D/g;
...
sum += parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML.replace(re,''), 10);
```

but you may need something with more complexity than that.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to implement that in to my code... basically I want to omit the entire alphabet, that way the script doesn't look at them and only adds numbers.

Comment: Wait, nevermind... this is what I need! Sorry, I'm a real n00b at Javascript.

Comment: The regular expression (`/\D/g`) will remove any non–digit character, including periods, + and - signs. If you want to recognise other patterns as numbers (e.g. `'-3.51'`), change the regular expression.